# Solidification Problems in MMA

Tags: equation-solving, finite-element-method, numerical-value, finite-difference-method

can we define such intial value and BCs for a **solidification  problem** in MMA using Finite Element:

1.) initial value:=1 for a plate

2.) in this plate we have to define dirichlet bcs for a whole circle area.
[image]

** My Code**

```
(*Initial Parameters*)Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Kappa = 1/10.0;
xmin = -1.0;
xmax = 1.;
ymin = -1.;
ymax = 1.0;

\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}];
RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/1000];
mesh["Wireframe"]
n = Length[mesh["Coordinates"]]
u0 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, RandomReal[{1, 1}, n]];
Plot3D[u0[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh]

\[CapitalOmega]1 = Disk[{0, 0}, xmax/10];
RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega]1, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
mesh1 = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega]1, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/1000];
mesh1["Wireframe"]
(*n=Length[mesh1["Coordinates"]]
u01=ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh1},0.5-RandomReal[{0,1},n]];
Plot3D[u01[x,y],{x,y}\[Element]mesh1]*)


u = NDSolveValue[{d[x, y] - 1. - 
      4*Kappa*Kappa*Laplacian[d[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[d[x, y] == 0, \[CapitalOmega]1], d[x, y] == 0},
    d, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]];
```

Comment: Edges that are not boundary edges are usually ignored by `DirichletCondition` IIRC, when you have a mesh for $\varOmega$ that also meshes $\varOmega_1$ well, then you can mark the edges that approximate $\partial \varOmega_1$ as "boundary" with the help of ElementMarkers so that you can employ boundary conditions. So watch out for questions on this site related to "ElementMarkers"; user21 has explained frequently how they work.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html#180054820

Comment: Well, that means you have to solve only the outer boundary value problem, no?

Comment: Please, write those details in your questions. Actually, I (and most likely also all other users) do not understand what you are writing about. _This is a systematic problem with your posts._ Please, adopt the habit to write complete sentences and outline all relevant detail.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's consider the following resrictions of the function $d$ that you are looking for: $u_1 := d |_{\varOmega_1}$ and $u_2 := d |_{\varOmega_2}$ with $\varOmega_2 = \varOmega \setminus \varOmega_1$. They satisfy the following PDE:

$$ 
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\kappa^2 \Delta u_ 1 - u_1 &= 1 &&\text{on $\varOmega_1$,} \\
\Delta u_1 &= 0 &&\text{on $\partial\varOmega_1$,} \\
\end{aligned}
\right.$$
and
$$ 
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\kappa^2 \Delta u_ 2 - u_2 &= 1 &&\text{on $\varOmega_2$,} \\
\Delta u_2 &= 0 &&\text{on $\partial\varOmega_2$.} \\
\end{aligned}
\right.$$
The point is that the Dirichlet conditions completely decouple the two regions. So you can simply solve the two PDE independently of each other.